# Applying for American visa in a country I was not born in

Tags: visas, swedish-citizens

I was born in Syria but moved to Sweden for 30 years ago, I am a Swedish citizen and passport says Swedish as nationality (issued by Sweden).

Now in applying for American visa they as the question:

Country/Region of origin (nationality):

after that they ask if i hold any other nationalities.

My question is, should the country of origin be syria, where I was born, or sweden? I got two options:

Country of origin (nationality): Sweden
Other country of origin: Syria

Or

Country of origin: Syria
Other country of origin: Sweden.

How should I answer this question? I am applying for the visa in Sweden.

Comment: @phoog: Oh, of course. Sorry for the nonsense.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes, nonsense it is (not your comment, but the policy), and it looks very much like it will get worse before it gets better.

Comment: Some internet research suggests that "country of origin (nationality)" must be the country whose passport you intend to use when you travel to the US.  I can't find a definitive source for this, though, which is why I am not posting an answer.  If this is correct, then you should use the first option if you are planning to travel with your Swedish passport.  If you have a Syrian passport and plan to use that then you should use the second option.  It's quite clear, however, that the answer does not depend on the location where you are applying.

Answer (score 3):

This question is confusing, because in English, "country of origin" means the country where you were born.

However, the question is not asking where you were born, (which was on the previous page) but is actually asking for your *nationality*. Unfortunately, the help for this question doesn't appear unless you select Yes to holding more than one nationality.

> Enter all nationalities you currently hold and all nationalities you have previously held, regardless of whether you have formally and/or legally relinquished the nationality. If the country where you previously held nationality is no longer a political entity or country, select the nationality that corresponds with the name of the country that is currently used for that location.

[image: CEAC Personal 2 Screenshot]

Given that the question is actually about nationality, rather than where you were born, you should answer SWEDEN for your nationality. If you are or were a Syrian citizen, you can enter SYRIA in the second box; otherwise, leave it unset.